# Select plain array against array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table looking like:

Table_A

```
| name | email_addresses                                 |
| a    | ['test@test.com']                               |
| b    | ['test@test.com', 'test2@test.com']             |
| c    | ['aatest@test.com', 'bbtest2@test.com']         |
| d    | ['test@test.com', 'test2@test.com', 'aa@bb.cc'] |
```

The field type of email_addresses is JSONB

In simple SQL, my query is like:

```
select * from Table_A where email_addresses = ['test@test.com', 'test2@test.com']
```

Which result should be : a, c, d

But not sure how to build this query in postgress json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `?|` operator to compare the value of your array with the json field

```
select * from my_table where email_addresses::jsonb ?| array['test@test.com', 'test2@test.com'];
```

[DBfiddle Deme](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gjKZgGwZBFhz8jvUzHatY1/3)